# Generate all possible combinations from a int list under a limit

Tags: python, list, optimization, combinations

I need to do this in Python.
There is a given list l,may contain more than 5000 integer elements.
There is a limit on sum of the numbers,20000 or may be high.
The output should be all the possible sums of 2 numbers picked from list,
Like,

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
output 
1+1,1+2,1+3,1+4,1+5,1+6...........
2+2,2+3,2+4.......
.........
.......

2,3,4,5,6... like that
```

I'm using this code,Doing this for now,
But It's slow

```
l=listgen()
p=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range(i,len(l)):
        k=l[i]+l[j]
        if k not in p:
            p.append(k)
p.sort
print(p)
```

`listgen()` is the function that generating the input list.

Comment: Use http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.combinations

Comment: What do you mean by limit? A limit on the sum, or on the length of the input list?

Comment: Limit on sum.sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: @Madushan You should add that to the question now :) Also sum of all elemens or each pair?

Comment: Added :D Each pair,I think that can clearly see on the code.Anyway thanx

Comment: What is too slow for you, and what is fast enough? (I'm assuming that you've profiled your code and that this is in fact a bottleneck...)

Comment: I'm trying to do [link]http://projecteuler.net/problem=23 so it's too slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some old-fashioned optimization might get you faster code that's easier to grok than list comprehensions with multiple for loops:

```
def sums(lst, limit):    # prevent global lookups by using a function
    res = set()          # set membership testing is much faster than lists
    res_add = res.add    # cache add method
    for i, first in enumerate(lst):   # get index and item at the same time
        for second in lst[i:]:        # one copy operation saves n index ops.
            res_add(first + second)   # prevent creation/lookup of extra local temporary
    return sorted([x for x in res if x < limit])

print sums(listgen(), 20000)
```

as an added bonus, this version will optimize beautifully with psyco, cython, etc.

**Update:**
When comparing this to the other suggestions (replacing listgen with range(5000), I get:

```
mine:        1.30 secs
WolframH:    2.65 secs
lazyr:       1.54 secs (estimate based on OPs timings -- I don't have Python 2.7 handy)
```

Comment: @Madushan I tried running your code as well, but it took too long and I had to kill the process :-(

Comment: With psyco mine went down to 0.7 secs :-)

Comment: That's 4.30 and 9.10 on my system with Python 3.2.Any way the list originally has 6965 elements and the limit is 28132.I never thought using a set() will speed me up this much.I have lot to learn!!.

Comment: +1 Nice overview of optimalizaton techniques! I'm not sure about the `lst[i:]` copy though, have you compared it with indexing directly into `lst`?

Comment: @lazyr using list indices for the inner loop brings the time up to 1.58 secs -- remember that indexing does a lot of work (something like `lst[j] => lst.__getitem__(j) => (getattr(lst, '__getitem__')(j)`). This isn't C :-)  Copying the list, otoh, is performed deep down in CPython-land, hopefully by calling memcpy or some such.

Comment: yours
4.517999887466431;
WolframH
9.116999864578247;
lazyr
5.380000114440918;
seems your code is the champion :D

Comment: I've updated the comparisons with a proportional estimate based on your timings.

Comment: Does it help if you collapse the nested loops into one big set comprehension? Or if you turn the list comprehension (in `sorted`) into a generator expression?

Comment: @WolframH changing the list comprehension in `sorted` into a generator can't possibly help, since the first thing sorted will do is to traverse the generator (but it's only 0.03 secs slower on my machine). I don't have a Python version with set comprehensions handy, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Thebjorn says he has the most efficient solution, and my own tests agree, though I've improved my performance a little. His code is also less dependent on python version and seems to be very well thought out and explained with regards to optimalization. You should accept his answer (and give him upvotes).

Use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) (added in python 2.7), and make `p` a `set`.

```
def sums(lst, limit):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
    p = set(x + y for x, y in combinations_with_replacement(listgen(), 2))
    return sorted([x for x in p if x < limit])
```

Your code is slow because of this line:

```
if k not in p: # O(N) lookup time in lists vs average case O(1) in sets
```

If you just make a couple of small changes to your code so that `p` is a `set`, it would make a huge difference:

```
L = listgen()
p = set()
for i in range(0, len(L)):
    for j in range(i, len(L)):
        p.add(L[i] + L[j])
print(sorted(p))
```

By the way, this line in your example

```
p.sort
```

has no effect. You must call a method to actually execute it, like so:

```
p.sort()
```

Comment: How should i able to use the limit?I don't want numbers more than it.

Comment: `l` is a bad variable name since it can be confused with `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Included the limit (which was not in the OP's code).

```
a = set(x + y for x in l for y in l)
print(sorted(x for x in a if x < limit))
```

That also reduces the complexity of the algorithm (yours is potentially O(n^4) because of the membership testing in a list).

Comment: I think this will take more time than my one.

Comment: @Madushan: What makes you think so? In my test, it was about 50 times faster than yours.

Comment: may be it's the set() but you are also doing what i'm doing isn't it?(going trough the entire list)*list elimants.

Comment: @Madushan: Some hings your code does and mine doesn't: Create range objects, look up items by indexing, look up lots of names, look up attribute `p.append` each time, call the looked up method, membership testing in lists (s-l-o-w).

Answer (score 1):

If the input list is sorted, you can break out of the inner loop when you reach the limit. Also, make `p` a set.

```
lst=listgen()
lst.sort()
p=set()
for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    for j in range(i,len(lst)):
        k=lst[i]+lst[j]
        if k > limit:
            break
        p.add(k)
p = sorted(p)
print(p)
```

Comment: Input list is sorted.I'v made the modification you told.Any way it's too slow yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "NumPy" for this.
This gives you definetly the required performance:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(5000)
limit = 20000
result = np.zeros(0,dtype='i4')
for i in data:
    result = np.concatenate((result,data[i]+data[i:]))
    if len(result) >= limit: break
result = result[:limit]
```

**EDIT:**
I just realized that the limit is on the sum and not on the number of elements. Then the code should read:

**EDIT2:**
Found further logical errors. My corrected suggestion is:

```
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(data):
    result = np.concatenate((result,x+data[idx[0]:]))
    if x + data[-1] >= limit: break
result = result[result <= limit]
```

Comment: I haven't used NumPy for anything yet.May be it's the time to start.Thank you

Comment: The last line seems to be a syntax error (sorry, don't know numpy well enough to figure out if that is correct or if you've interpreted the limit incorrectly -- see the other answers...?)

Comment: @thebjorn: of course - you are right - I confused the brackets. Corrected this now. Thank you!

Comment: @thebjorn: Aaaah - now I see what you meant. The limit is on the sum, not the number of elements...

Answer (score 0):

If the list can contain repeated elements it might be a wise idea to get rid of them first, e.g. by converting the list to a set.

Comment: There is no repeated items in the input.I optimized the other code to make sure of it.